# Force through "TypeError: Cannot read "key" of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I have a horribly nested object where everything is in arrays with one element. Depending on the object the elements and depth vary. Something like this:

```
var horribleObj = {
  "key": ['String'],
  "key2": [{
    "key3": [
      "string"
    ],
    "key4": [{
      "key5": [
        "string"
      ]
    }]
  }]
}
```

I would like to clean it by looping over an array of `horribleObj` and obviously it throws an error if I try using a key that's not present. Also `key2` might be missing on some iterations.

```
var goodObj = {
    "myKey": horribleObj.key2[0].key6[0]
}
```

However this `key6` is present on some `horribleObj`. Is there a way to keep going here without javascript throwing an error and without checking the object for existence every nested possibility? I'm OK with this to result in `"myKey": null`

This is quite a large array with huge `horribleObj` and I need to query quite a few keys. I would very much like to avoid writing `if()` chains for each en every one of them.

Comment: only way would be to test its existance before setting it....

Comment: `"myKey": horribleObj.key2[0].key6 ? horribleObj.key2[0].key6[0] : null`

Comment: You can check it using hasOwnProperty

Comment: And with your edit " avoid writing if() chains", well there really is not a way to avoid it. You can abstract it out to a method and have that walk the tree for you, plenty of libraries do it.

Comment: Well there is this: `var level3 = (((test || {}).level1 || {}).level2 || {}).level3;
alert( level3 );`Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4034468/3047245
Not sure if I like this syntax though...

Answer (score 0):

Ok a couple of possibilities:

1. Testing for existence with `if()` statements or `hasOwnProperty`possibly wrapped up in a function and returning value or null
2. Testing existence inline with this syntax (apparently fastest version):

   `var level3 = (((test || {}).level1 || {}).level2 || {}).level3; 
   alert( level3 );`
3. Using lodash `_.get()`:

   `_.get(horribleObj, ['key1', 0 , 'key2' , 0])`

I went with lodash in the end as it's very convenient and speed wasn't the issue.

Few more [here including speedtests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)